# Does leaflet.js offer an gutter option just like Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, leaflet, deegree

Currently we are switching from Openlayers to leaflet.js and there is a problem using a WMS layer with leaflet. The WMS being used is Deegree. When a layer is visualised within leaflet there are artifacts at the tile edges as seen in the added picture.

With openlayers we fixed it with a [gutter](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.gutter) option. Is there a similar solution for leaflet?

[image: Tile Edge problem]

Answer (score 1):

Don't tested but try setting it as a new parameter on L.TileLayer.WMS. At least the code seems does not filters parameters (https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/tile/TileLayer.WMS.js).

On the other hand, it is also better you configure your WMS server to solve the problem at servir side. This way no matter of client you will not have problems.